# Vorbis SPI throws UnsupportedAudioFileException for OGG files

Tags: java, ogg, spi, vorbis

I'm trying to play an OGG Vorbis file from a Java program.
PCM files (*.wav) work fine with this code:

```
public void play(String resFile) throws Exception {
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;

    URL audioSource = new File(resFile).toURL();
    audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioSource);

    AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
    SourceDataLine line = null;
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);

    line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    line.open(format);

    line.start();
    int bytesRead = 0;
    byte[] data = new byte[32 * 1024];

    try {
        audioInputStream.mark(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        while(bytesRead != -1) {
            bytesRead = audioInputStream.read(data, 0, data.length);
            if(bytesRead >= 0) {
                line.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            Thread.yield();
        }
    } finally {
        line.drain();
        line.close();
    }
}
```

In order to be able to play OGG files as well, I downloaded [Vorbis SPI](http://www.javazoom.net/vorbisspi/sources.html) and put the jar in the classpath. I tried with [this sample ogg from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aExample.ogg). But it still doesn't work, it gives me an UnsupportedAudioFileException.

Do you know what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Oops... turns out I didn't have all the dependencies in my classpath: tritonus_share.jar, jorbis-0.0.15.jar, jogg-0.0.7.jar.